# Is hypothesis test an intuitionist approach?

Tags: hypothesis-testing

In statistics, the hypothesis testing is used for determining whether the null hypothesis can be rejected or failed to reject. For example, we use hypothesis testing in order determine the significance of the estimator in linear regression:

$H_0: \beta_1 = 0 \ \ \ H_1 : \beta_1 \neq 0$

My question is the approach of hypothesis testing in statistics related to intuitionist where the proof by contradiction is not permitted? Or to the classical reasoning?

Since, our main objective here is to show that $\beta_1$ is different from $0$, which means that the explanatory variable affects the dependent variable. In the above case we assumed that the parameter $\beta_1$ is equal to $0$. Thus, if we do not find enough proof that $\beta_1 = 0$, we reject the null hypothesis, which we conclude that $\beta_1 \neq 0$.

Comment: There is always a possibility to make an error , so the result is never a purely mathematical result , but a result correct with high probability.

Comment: See [Cohen (1994)](https://users.cla.umn.edu/~nwaller/prelim/cohenearthround.pdf) for why proof-by-contradiction does not work with probabilistic logic.

Comment: First, I see nothing here that involves proof by contradiction. In math, that refers to assuming something to be true and then showing that it leads to absurdities. This does not. It just shows that it's unlikely (maybe very unlikely) not impossible  Getting 20 heads in a row with a fair coin is very weird, but it's not like there being a highest prime. Second, it is not *assumed* that $B_1 = 0, at least, not in the mathematical sense (more like in the sense of  a criminal trial).

Comment: I somewhat fail to decipher the post due to some grammar issues. And asking if something is "related" is often too vague. In any case, if the question is about the proof of something discrete or negative ($\neg P$), then it's likely not so related. Some clarifications: Intuitionists do not reject $(P\to\bot)\to\neg P$. When people call this "proof by contradiction", then this can lead to ambiguity, even if that wouldn't be the worst name for it. Intuitionists do reject $(\neg\neg P)\to P$ as a principle. But whenever $P\lor\neg P$ is provable, this holds also - by the disjunctive syllogism.